# how can i web scraping getting number from this code

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get number from this site i think my code is fine but my list become empty.can someone help me?

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector
num = 1
list3 = []
url = ('https://bama.ir/car/lifan/all-models/all-trims?page=')
r = requests.get(url + str(num))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
res_year = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'mid'})
for item in res_year:
    z = re.findall(r'<span class="price year-label hidden-xs" itemprop="releaseDate">(\d+)،&nbsp;</span>',str(item))
    print(z)
    list3 += z
for item in list3:
    print(item)
```

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question, especially if that data is from an external/unreachable resource.  the easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - If you read with a critical eye, that is included/implied in [mcve]. - please include a **minimal example** of the markup.

Comment: ok.sorry for my bad english.I want to get the numbers in that site and my list3 must like this list3 = [1398,1387,1385,...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
num = 1
list3 = []
url = ('https://bama.ir/car/lifan/all-models/all-trims?page=')
r = requests.get(url + str(num))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

txt = (t.text for t in soup.find_all("span", class_="price year-label hidden-xs"))
for i in txt:
    i = i.rstrip("،\xa0")
    print(i)
```

The output:

```
1395
1393
1394
1395
1395
1396
1392
1397
1395
1394
1397
1395
1393
1395
1394
1397
1394
1396
1395
1392
1395
1395
1395
1395
1392
1393
1395
1393
1393
1397
```

The first mistake, it's:

```
r"""<span class="price year-label hidden-xs" itemprop="releaseDate">(\d*?)، </span>"""
```

**not :**

```
r'<span class="price year-label hidden-xs" itemprop="releaseDate">(\d+)،&nbsp;</span>'
```

The second mistake, it's the utility of `re.findall()`:

> Re.findall() module is used when you want to iterate over the lines of
>   the file, it will return a list of all the matches in a single step.

Therefore: there is no reason to iterate the `res_years` and execute the 
`re.findall()` method on the items of it, the code will be at the end:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
num = 1
list3 = []
url = ('https://bama.ir/car/lifan/all-models/all-trims?page=')
r = requests.get(url + str(num))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
res_year = soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'price year-label hidden-xs'})
z = re.findall(r"""<span class="price year-label hidden-xs" itemprop="releaseDate">(\d*?)، </span>""",str(res_year))
print(z)
```

The result:

```
['1395', '1393', '1394', '1395', '1395', '1396', '1392', '1397', '1395', '1394', '1397', '1395', '1393', '1395', '1394', '1397', '1394', '1396', '1395', '1392', '1395', '1395', '1395', '1395', '1392', '1393', '1395', '1393', '1393', '1397']
```

Comment: can you breifly explain the last 4 line for me?

Comment: thank a lot for the answer.did you know a course or a book that help me in web scrapping?

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow strives to be a professional knowledge base. Thus, write "you"instead of "u" please. Also you might want to dial down on the bold-formatting, as it makes text more difficult to read and it is unnecessary, at least in my opinion. Reserve it for single words which need emphasis, or paragraph headings. Not being a native speaker, I am neither, and making mistakes in English is fine, but try and keep it professional please.

Comment: You are welcome, my best book it's "AUTOMATE THE BORING STUFF WITH PYTHON"                                                                                                                    Thank you! @Adriaan

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = req.get('https://bama.ir/car/lifan/all-models/all-trims?page=1')

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html) # The library is lighter and the code written is easier to understand
lst = doc.getElementsByClass('price year-label hidden-xs') # Similar to DOM operation of JS
for i in lst:
    i = i.text.rstrip('، ')
    print(i)
```